# jquery file upload queue with formdata

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am trying to upload files one by one using this script i made but instead it uploads them all at once.

files_obj store the files inputted through the html input element.

```
var files_obj = {};

var uploading = false;

function upload_all()
{               
    $.each(files_obj, function(i, file) {

        if( !uploading )
        {
            uploading = true;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            var formdata = new FormData();

            fd.append("file",file);

            xhr.open('POST','upload.php',true);
            xhr.send(formdata);
            uploading = false;

        }
    });
}
```

the variable "uploading" stores the current status of the file being uploaded, so when it has been uploaded it is set to false and the next file in the queue should upload.

Comment: What do you mean with one by one? Do you mean in differents actions?

Comment: in different xhr requests.

Comment: I think the files are sending one by one. You can add `console.log(i+":"+file);` to see the progress.

Comment: they are all added to the console at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function upload_sequentially(input, callback){
  var files = [], current = 0;
  if (input instanceof HTMLInputElement && input.type === 'file') {
    files = input.files;
  } else if (input instanceof FileList || Array.isArray(input)) {
    files = input;
  } else if (typeof input === 'object') {
    for (var key in input) {
      if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) files.push(input[key]);
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid input');
  }
  if (files.length === 0) return callback(null);
  return (function upload(file){
    var formdata = new FormData(), xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    formdata.append('file', file);
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
      var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total * 100 | 0) + '% complete';
      console.log('Upload #' + current + ' is ' + percentComplete );
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e){
      if (xhr.status >= 400) {
        callback(new Error('Unable to upload'));
      } else if (current === files.length - 1) {
        callback(null);
      } else {
        upload(files[++current]);
      }
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', callback, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('abort', callback, false);
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
    xhr.send(formdata);
  })(files[0]);
}
```

You'd then need to pass it an array-like object of files and a callback function:

```
upload_sequentially(files, function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Uploaded all ' + files.length + ' files');
  }
});
```

Comment: that has worked thanks. it is continually logging to console even after all have been uploaded and how come it doesn't show the request in chrome network tab.

Comment: @sam what is it logging to console after all the files have been uploaded? The requests should **definitely** be showing up in the network tab so I'm not sure how that could be happening.

Comment: its logging upload #++ is 100% complete.

Comment: @sam where does the `files` object that you're passing into this function come from? A file input, a drag/drop event, what?

Comment: files are stored in an object when added to file input

Comment: @sam It needs to be an array, can you try adding `files = $.map(files, function(i,v){ return v })` before passing `files` to the function?

Comment: thats not worked. i dont think you can upload files from an array, it has to be an object.

Comment: @sam can you tell me what `Object.keys(files)` outputs for you?

Comment: it stores the file name

Comment: @sam I've updated my answer in an attempt to accept an `Array`, `FileList`, or plain `Object`. Please take a look.

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection.

Comment: @sam it sounds like you're trying to pass the actual `<input type="file" name="files">` DOM node into this function. That won't work. You need to extract the `.files` property from the `HTMLInputElement` DOM node and pass that into the function instead.

Comment: @sam I've updated my answer to **also** handle getting passed an `HTMLInputElement` DOM node. Please take another look.